# Find the points of discontinuity of the graph and also draw the graph in rough

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions, continuity

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
  sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}(x-[x]))  & \text{for }[x] \space is \space odd, x\ge0\\    
  cos(\dfrac{\pi}{4}(1-x+[x]))  & \text{for }[x] \space is \space even,x\ge0 
\end{cases}$

where $[x]$ is the largest integer smaller than or equal to x

(i)Sketch the graph of $f(x)$ on plain paper

(ii)Determine the points of dicontinuities of $f$ and the points where $f$ is not differentiable

**My attempt**

The graph looks like a wave where there is no negative half and it reaches its crest at every even integer and reaches 0 at every odd integer starting from 0 as $x\ge0$ i.e it alternates between $0 \space \text{&} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

At every integer where $[x]$ is either even or odd, it is discontinuous and not differentiable

Am I right? I cannot take a snapshot of the graph as many users do not advocate in favor of it. If you insist I can do that for you. Please draw the graph and let me know whether I am wrong or right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

As you noticed the only points where there is something to investigate are $x\in \Bbb Z$.

- For $x=(2n+1)^+$ you have $[x]=2n+1$ and:
  $$f(x)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}((2n+1)^+-(2n+1)) \right)=\sin(0)=0$$
  For $x=(2n+1)^-$ you have $[x]=2n$ and:
  $$f(x)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1-(2n+1)^-+2n\right) \right)=\cos(0)=1$$
- For $x=(2n)^+$ you have $[x]=2n$ and:
  $$f(x)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1-(2n)^++2n\right) \right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
  For $x=(2n)^-$ you have $[x]=2n-1$ and:
  $$f(x)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\left((2n)^--(2n-1)\right) \right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

So in fact $f$ is continuous on even integers.

To study if $f$ is differentiable you also have to study $f$ near the integers the same way.

---

Here is the plot of the function I have obtained:
[image: plot]

Comment: Can you please let me know which software you used to draw this graph. I need to know please.

Comment: But I must say that if $\lim_{x\to(2n+1)^-} f(x)$ $\neq$  $\lim_{x\to(2n+1)^+} f(x)$ But $\lim_{x\to(2n)^-} f(x)$=$\lim_{x\to(2n)^+} f(x)$ as what is seen from your answer. Thus $f(x)$ is continuous at even integers - right? You have written the other way round in your answer.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it is continuous at even integers and not odd ones, I will correct my answer.

Comment: And for the plot I used python (more precisely matplotlib).

Comment: Oh matplotlib- I also have python. Ok thanks!